# Group by date in mongoose/mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Note: Mongo version 3.6.2.

I have a document that looks like this:

```
const Ticket = new mongoose.Schema({
    event_id: [
        {
            required: false,
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Event'
        }
    ],
    ticket_type: String,
    createdAt: String,
}, { collection: 'tickets' });
```

I want to do a mongodb groupBy on `ticket_type` and `createdAt` where an event_id = X. So the output should like this:

```
[{ ticket_type: 'VIP', date: 2011-11-11, count: 12}, {..}]
```

The hard part is that `createdAt` is stored as timemillis in a string, ex:

```
{
    _id : ObjectId(123), 
    ticket_type: 'VIP', 
    createdAt: '1233434', 
    event_id: [ObjectId(345)]
}
```

The answer should look something like this:

```
    Ticket.find({ event_id: req.params.event_id }, function(err, tickCount) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.json(tickCount);
        }
    });
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

This is what I came up with:

```
  Ticket.aggregate([

      {  $match: { event_id: ObjectId(req.body.event_id)} },
      {
    $addFields: {
        "createdAt": {
            $reduce: {
                "input": {
                    $map: { // split string into char array so we can loop over individual characters
                        "input": {
                            $range: [ 0, { $strLenCP: "$createdAt" } ] // using an array of all numbers from 0 to the length of the string
                        },
                        "in":{
                            $substrCP: [ "$createdAt", "$$this", 1 ] // return the nth character as the mapped value for the current index
                        }
                    }
                },
                "initialValue": { // initialize the parser with a 0 value
                    "n": 0, // the current number
                    "sign": 1, // used for positive/negative numbers
                    "div": null, // used for shifting on the right side of the decimal separator "."
                    "mult": 10 // used for shifting on the left side of the decimal separator "."
                }, // start with a zero
                "in": {
                    $let: {
                        "vars": {
                            "n": {
                                $switch: { // char-to-number mapping
                                    branches: [
                                        { "case": { $eq: [ "$$this", "1" ] }, "then": 1 },
                                        { "case": { $eq: [ "$$this", "2" ] }, "then": 2 },
                                        { "case": { $eq: [ "$$this", "3" ] }, "then": 3 },
                                        { "case": { $eq: [ "$$this", "4" ] }, "then": 4 },
                                        { "case": { $eq: [ "$$this", "5" ] }, "then": 5 },
                                        { "case": { $eq: [ "$$this", "6" ] }, "then": 6 },
                                        { "case": { $eq: [ "$$this", "7" ] }, "then": 7 },
                                        { "case": { $eq: [ "$$this", "8" ] }, "then": 8 },
                                        { "case": { $eq: [ "$$this", "9" ] }, "then": 9 },
                                        { "case": { $eq: [ "$$this", "0" ] }, "then": 0 },
                                        { "case": { $and: [ { $eq: [ "$$this", "-" ] }, { $eq: [ "$$value.n", 0 ] } ] }, "then": "-" }, // we allow a minus sign at the start
                                        { "case": { $eq: [ "$$this", "." ] }, "then": "." }
                                    ],
                                    default: null // marker to skip the current character
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "in": {
                            $switch: {
                                "branches": [
                                    {
                                        "case": { $eq: [ "$$n", "-" ] },
                                        "then": { // handle negative numbers
                                            "sign": -1, // set sign to -1, the rest stays untouched
                                            "n": "$$value.n",
                                            "div": "$$value.div",
                                            "mult": "$$value.mult",
                                        },
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "case": { $eq: [ "$$n", null ] }, // null is the "ignore this character" marker
                                        "then": "$$value" // no change to current value
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "case": { $eq: [ "$$n", "." ] },
                                        "then": { // handle decimals
                                            "n": "$$value.n",
                                            "sign": "$$value.sign",
                                            "div": 10, // from the decimal separator "." onwards, we start dividing new numbers by some divisor which starts at 10 initially
                                            "mult": 1, // and we stop multiplying the current value by ten
                                        },
                                    },
                                ],
                                "default": {
                                    "n": {
                                        $add: [
                                            { $multiply: [ "$$value.n", "$$value.mult" ] }, // multiply the already parsed number by 10 because we're moving one step to the right or by one once we're hitting the decimals section
                                            { $divide: [ "$$n", { $ifNull: [ "$$value.div", 1 ] } ] } // add the respective numerical value of what we look at currently, potentially divided by a divisor
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "sign": "$$value.sign",
                                    "div": { $multiply: [ "$$value.div" , 10 ] },
                                    "mult": "$$value.mult"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $addFields: { // fix sign
        "createdAt": { $multiply: [ "$createdAt.n", "$createdAt.sign" ] }
    }
},
      {
          $group: {
              _id: {
                  ticket_type: "$ticket_type",
                  createdAt: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: { $add: [ new Date(0), "$createdAt" ] }} },
                  count: { $sum: 1 }
              }
          }
      },
            { $sort: { "createdAt": 1 } }
  ], function(err, tickCount) {
      if (err) {
          console.log(err);
      } else {
          res.json(tickCount);
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) aggregation pipeline stage. To convert string to number you can use [$toLong](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toLong/index.html) operator and then you can use [$add](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/index.html) (works for ISODate as well) to add that value to the date with zero miliseconds `(new Date(0))` to get `ISODate`. Try:

```
Ticket.aggregate([
    {  $match: { event_id: req.params.event_id } },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                ticket_type: "$ticket_type",
                createdAt: { $add: [ new Date(0), { $toLong: "$createdAt" } ] }
            }
        }
    } 
], function(err, tickCount) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        res.json(tickCount);
    }
});
```

EDIT: assuming that you manually converted string to number you can run following query to aggregate on date part of ISODate:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {  $match: { event_id: req.params.event_id } },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                ticket_type: "$ticket_type",
                createdAt: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date:{ $add: [ new Date(0), "$createdAt" ] } } },
                count: { $sum: 1 }
            }
        }
    },
    { $sort: { "_id.createdAt": 1 } }
])
```

Comment: I tried that line of code and got   errmsg: 'Unrecognized expression \'$toLong\'',
  code: 168,
  codeName: 'InvalidPipelineOperator',
  name: 'MongoError',

Comment: Im using mongo version 3.6.2

Comment: $toLong is available in MongoDB 4.0, you have to fix your schema and "manually" convert strings to numbers

Comment: Ok, mick1 I did what you suggested, but now I get ticket_type and date, I want date, not datetime and I want the count per each date

Comment: Actually I have it with date, I just want the count now

Comment: Modified my answer, `count: { $sum: 1}` is the part you're currently missing

Comment: @pavbagel added :)